# Why Won't My Forecasts Calculate When Opportunity Data Is Created?

Tags: opportunity, forecast, customizable-forecasts

I have created a batch to aggregate our order data into `Opportunity` and `OpportunityLineItem` records so that it will feed into the out-of-the-box `Customizable Forecasting` module. The `Opportunity` data is coming through more or less as expected, but the forecast records aren't calculating!

I enabled all relevant users in the `Forecast Hierarchy` at least a week ago. It has been over a day since the `Opportunity` data was created. I also made sure the `Opportunity` records have the correct `ForecastCategory` and `Quantity` values:

[image: Forecasting Opportunity Data]

The product families are set up and if I drill down to the `OpportunityLineItem` data, there are records with the expected values there as well.

Is there anything else I can check to get this data to roll up into the forecasting module? Here's a screenshot of my `Forecast Settings` for reference:

[image: Forecast Settings]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course I found this article after posting a bounty:

> ## [Revenue or Quantity not up-to-date in Forecasts tab for Customizable Forecasts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000240617&type=1&language=en_US)
>
> Knowledge Article Number 000240617
>
> **Description**
>   Some users may notice a mismatch between Revenue and Quantity when viewing forecasts in the Forecasts tab.
>
> **Resolution**
>   This would typically happen if the Forecast calculation is in progress.  You'll notice the Forecasts Recalculation icon ([image: Forecasts Recalculation icon]) on the header of columns that are still being calculated.  Wait a few moments to allow the calculation enough time to process then refresh the page.  If the calculation hasn't completed within 24 hours please log a case through the help portal and include as much details as possible about the forecast in the Case Description.

I revisited the `Forecasts` tab and what do you know:

[image: Forecast calculation in progress]

It's been over 72 hours at this point, so I'll go ahead and log a case. Hopefully someone else will benefit from this Q&A. Bit of a dumb oversight...guess I just needed to step away and get some fresh eyes on the issue.